# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=10, result=-1, data=Intent

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-permissions

**EDIT**:

Now the app is working. But it only asks for the permission after the first time it is started(after installation). If I leave the app(pressing back button) and then later start it again it doesn't ask for the permission. Why is this happening?

Doesn't pressing the back button destroys the activity by calling onDestroy() and shouldn't it call onCreate() method again?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

My app allows the user to find their current location on the press of the button.Whenever the app is started for the first time, it asks for the user permission but it crashes when the permission is granted giving following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result 
ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=10, result=-1,
data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has
extras) }} to activity
{com.example.hpi5.location/com.example.hpi5.location.MainActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
on a null object reference
```

Below is my Activity code:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button ;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 ){
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        10);
                return;
            }
        }

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        locationManager = (LocationManager)
                getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                //double speed = location.getSpeed(); //spe2d in meter/minute
                //speed = (speed*3600)/1000;      // speed in km/minute
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lat" + latitude + "lon" + longitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };




    }
    void requestUpdate(){
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[], @ NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case -1:{
                //hello
            }

            case 10: {
                if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestUpdate();
                }
            }

        }
    }



}
```

Below is the logcat error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=10, result=-1,
data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has
extras) }} to activity
{com.example.hpi5.location/com.example.hpi5.location.MainActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
    android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
     on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                                           at
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
     method 'void
  android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
     on a null object reference
com.example.hpi5.location.MainActivity.requestUpdate(MainActivity.java:80)
     com.example.hpi5.location.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:95)
    android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:6553)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6432)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: That's because it does not find R.id.button in your layout

Comment: I fixed you code, see my answer. @rayan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You request the permission *before* initializing `button`, and I assume the callback completes before it has the chance to initialize the Button object fully. Try moving the permission check to the end of `onCreate`, or failing that, double check the button's ID is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Edits made `Coarse Permission`, button init. `onCreate()` and break ponit added `onRequestPermissionsResult()`.

As the error is saying is `NullPointException` caused by null object of `Button`:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button ;
LocationListener locationListener;
LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            requestUpdate();
        }
    });

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                        (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,},
                    10);
            return;
        }
    }

    locationManager = (LocationManager)
            getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new LocationListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            //double speed = location.getSpeed(); //spe2d in meter/minute
            //speed = (speed*3600)/1000;      // speed in km/minute
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lat" + latitude + "lon" + longitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
}

void requestUpdate(){    
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[], @ NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case -1:
            //hello
            break;


        case 10: 
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestUpdate();
            }else{
            //do something if permission not granted.
            }
            break;

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ur help :)

Comment: sure we are here too help only

Comment: The app asks for the permission only after installing it for the first time and then if leave the app (pressing back button) and open it again it does not. Is this because of the fact that pressing back button only destroys the activity, not the application and application process is still around in the memory. So if I(or OS) kills the process it will again ask for permission.

Comment: If permission asked and u back pressed that activity goes from oncraete to onpause and coming back it comes to onresume. If u kill the app and come back it will ask again. So better check the permission on each state of activity mainly on `onCreate, onResume, onPause`. so make a general function to check permission and shot this function to the activity states I mentioned.

Comment: Pressing back button calls onDestroy() method(of course onPause() and onStop() are also called ). Doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but u must call in all activity cycle to know the status of permission

Answer (score 0):

Move line

```
 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

to the location after

```
setContentView(..);
```